# if not conditions in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

is there anything like "if not" conditions in R?

easy Example (not working):

```
fun <- function(x)
{
if (!x > 0) {print ("not bigger than zero")}
}

fun(5)
```

Comment: Your example works correctly.  Try `fun(0)`.  With 5, it says "if not 5 > 0".  5 is greater than 0, so that's `TRUE`, but the not makes it `FALSE`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is in how you are defining the condition. It should be

```
    if(!(x > 0)){
```

instead of

```
    if(!x > 0){
```

This is because `!x` converts the input (a numeric) to a logical - which will give `TRUE` for all values except zero. So:

```
> fun <- function(x){
+   if (!(x > 0)) {print ("not bigger than zero")}
+ }
> fun(1)
> fun(0)
[1] "not bigger than zero"
> fun(-1)
[1] "not bigger than zero"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
if(!condition) { do something }
```

Comment: I already tried that, but it's not the solution :-(
added a simple example above.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
fun <- function(x){
ifelse(x > 0, "not bigger than zero", "zero or less")
}
```

```
fun(5)
```

```
[1] "Bigger than zero"
```

Comment: ifelse should only be used for vectors of length > 1